The Jewish and English translations of Isaiah 9:6 shows it in 3 different tenses? What is really the original tense of the verbs in Isaiah 9:6?
The Jewish Bible shows it in the past tense. (from https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15940/jewish/Chapter-9.htm
The NLT shows Isaiah 9:6 in the present tense.
For a child is born to us, a son is given to us. The government will rest on his shoulders. And he will be called: Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace
The New American Standard Bible shows it in the future tense.
For a Child will be born to us, a Son will be given to us; And the government will rest on His shoulders; And His name will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace.

The Hebrew verbs do not have tense - they have aspect, but NOT tense.  The translator must make an interpretive decision when translating to a tense filled language like English and different translators make different decisions.  Therefore, the answer to this question is opinion based.

No, it's a translation-philosophy question which is clearly allowed on this site

I would translate it as:
For a child has been born to us, a son has been given to us (these are perfectly completed acts, for Jesus was slain before the foundation of the earth),
and the government is and will be" (in the sequence of time outworked) upon his shoulder, and His name is and will be called (in the sequence of time outworked)  "Pele, Wonders", "Yowesh, Counsellor", "El, God", "Gibour, A mighty man", "Abi, My father", "Ad, Eternal", " Sar-Shalom, The prince of Peace"
